# Buddha's Power of Seeing Other Beings Mind

Tags: pali-canon, terminology, buddha, psychic-powers, pali

What is the proper Pali word for Buddha's power of seeing other beings mind? I think it starts with **Paricitta** or something. I want the proper Pali term. Also, can I have any sutta references to it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Katamañca, kevaṭṭa, **ādesa­nā**­pā­ṭihā­ri­yaṃ? Idha, kevaṭṭa, bhikkhu parasattānaṃ parapuggalānaṃ cittampi ādisati, cetasikampi ādisati,
> vitakkitampi ādisati, vicāritampi ādisati: ‘evampi te mano, itthampi
> te mano, itipi te cittan’ti.*
>
> *And what is the miracle of **telepathy**? There is the case where a monk reads the minds, the mental events, the thoughts, the ponderings of
> other beings, other individuals, [saying,] 'Such is your thinking,
> here is where your thinking is, thus is your mind.'*
>
> *[Kevatta (Kevaddha) Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.11.0.than.html)*
>
> *ādesanā = pointing out, guessing, prophesy; only in phrase -pāṭihāriya trick or marvellous ability of mind-reading or guessing other peoples character*

---

> *Parasattānaṃ parapuggalānaṃ cetasā ceto **paricca** **pajānāti***
>
> *He **knows** the mind of other beings, other individuals, having **encompassed** it with his own mind.*
>
> *[Kayagata-Sati Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.119.than.html)*
>
> *paricca = distinguished or understood*
>
> *pajānāti = knows clearly*
>
> *para = other*
>
> *sattānaṃ = beings*'
>
> *puggalānaṃ = persons*
>
> *cetasā = minds*
>
> *ceto = mind*

---

> *[Hinduism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi): para citta ādi abhijñatā: knowing the minds of others*

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is `para citta vijana nana`

Pali:

- [Para](https://suttacentral.net/define/para) - another
- [Citta](https://suttacentral.net/define/citta) - mind
- [Vijana](https://suttacentral.net/define/vij%C4%81na) - understand
- [Nana](https://suttacentral.net/define/%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a) - knowledge

I.e., knowledge of another's mind.

This is also known as [ceto pariya ñāṇa](https://suttacentral.net/define/cetopariya%C3%B1%C4%81%E1%B9%87a).